# Is this FD compatible with this crankset: 2 teeth too few

Tags: derailleur, drivetrain

**TL;DR**:
Q: Can I use an SLX FD on an all SRAM rig?
A: Usually not. In the current case Trek Slash 7 2013 & Shimano M786 - no adjustment sufficed to produce a noise-free ride.

---

I am a proud owner of [this](http://www.trekbikes.com/us/en/bikes/2013/archive/trek/slash_7/#/us/en/archive-model/details?url=us/en/bikes/2013/archive/trek/slash_7) guy. The crankset is `SRAM S1200, 36/22` and the FD is `SRAM X7, direct mount`.

However, the cage on the FD broke, and I ordered [this](http://www.evanscycles.com/products/shimano/m786-xt-10-speed-double-front-derailleur-direct-mount-dual-pull-ec029255#features) item in a hurry.

```
1) Dyna-Sys 10-speed design – for use with Dyna-Sys 10-speed MTB drivetrains.

2) Specifically developed for 68 and 73 mm bottom bracket shells with a 48.8 mm chain line 

3) 66-69 degree chainstay to seat tube angle range.

4) 44-38 tooth outer ring compatible, total capacity 14 teeth
```

Questions:

1. I have heard Shimano and SRAM FDs are compatible  - is that true?
2. 73mm BB - check, 48.8mm chain line - how do I check this? Is it correct to measure with a ruler from the center of the frame to the middle of the two chainrings? I doubt I can get accurace better than a couple of mm.
3. 66-69 degrees chainstay - check - it it inscribed on the old FD.
4. The tooth capacity is OK, but my big ring is 2 teeth too large.

All in all, can this equipment work together or be made to work together, or do I need to toss it?

Comment: I have never heard that Shimano Dyna-sys is compatible with anything but Dyna-sys. However since it's a front derailler and is only a double it "might" work if anything does. Generally if you have SRAM shifters, you need SRAM deraillers. I would only attempt this if it was not possible to exchange the Shimano for the sram. SRAM deraillers generally have very different cable pull lengths than Shimano.

Comment: Did some more digging and it looks like SRAM and Shimano cable pulls for front deraillers are "close enough" that this might work.

Comment: Since you have it, bolt it on and see what happens. No point throwing it away just because you think it might not work.

Comment: Seems better to return it and get the sram part.

Comment: Is a [triple](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/bg/en/shimano-xt-m781-direct-mount-3x10-front-mech/rp-prod83625) suitable replacement for a double? What are the differences?

Comment: The framewards side of the cage is deeper on FDs for triples. This shouldn't reduce their function on doubles, but using a double-FD with a triple will give poor shifting on the smaller rings.

Comment: @Vorac did you ever find an answer for this ?

Comment: @Criggie heya, it didn't work and I needed to re-order the correct part now, haha. I was contemplating deleting the question due to dead links, lack of detail and lack of understanding of the outcome. But should probably leave it because of the comments. It will sink to oblivion anyway.

Comment: Just post this as an answer and it will remain there for others.